# Backbone.validation, validate without DOM updates

Tags: validation, backbone.js, backbone.validation.js

As expressed in this [backbone.validation issue](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation/issues/327), when using the plugin as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/miphe/udXL5/513/), we should get a validation performed by `isValid()` - without params.

If the `this.model.attributes` have changes, `isValid()` should validate the properties on `this.model.attributes` however that's not the case in the example.

---

What I'm aiming for is to constantly, when there's a change to a the model/form, re-evaluate the validity of the entire form, and based on the outcome enable or disable the submit button (in the fiddle example though, the validation will only happen when clicking the submit button).

I do not want to use `isValid(true)` because then all fields that have yet not been filled in will get validated by force.

The desired behavior is to validate the *dirty* fields, but also recognize that the *clean* fields aren't valid yet (thus not enabling submit button) - but *clean* fields shouldn't be validated visibly to disturb the user with errors, just under the hood, to enhance the behavior of the submit button.

Am I approaching this problem the wrong way with `backbone.validation`?

Comment: Well what I think is that you should have given some time for he author to get back to you with a response on that issue :)

Comment: Arguably so, yes. However I feel that it may be a problem/confusion others would run into as well, the answer would be easier to find here than in a closed issue on GH.